# Each letter typed in input is causing rerendering component in React Querybuilder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, query-builder

I'm using react query builder with MaterialUI and I found a bug in ValueEditor where each typed letter in TextField is causing rerendering.

Here is codesanbox example of same thing using regular input in ValueEditor.
https://codesandbox.io/s/oditj?file=/src/App.tsx

Anyone has any idea how to fix this problem?
I would appreciate any type of help
Thanks

Comment: Isn't it quite normal in React to rerender for each letter typed ? https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: Try using `useRef` hook

Comment: I would be very interested to hear solution using useRef would you be kind explaining it to me? @User456

Comment: You should add the code to the question for future references (codesandbox could be unavailable in the future)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the `ValueEditor` component outside the `App` component because it's being re-created in each "App" render, which triggers another render.

Before:

```
  const App = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState<RuleGroupType>({
    id: 'root',
    combinator: 'and',
    rules: [],
  });

  const ValueEditor = ({ handleOnChange, value }: ValueEditorProps) => (
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value)}
      value={value}
    />
  );

  return (
    <QueryBuilder
      fields={[{ name: 'test', label: 'Test' }]}
      controlElements={{ valueEditor: ValueEditor }}
      onQueryChange={(q) => setQuery(q)}
      query={query}
    />
  );
};
```

After:

```
const ValueEditor = ({ handleOnChange, value }: ValueEditorProps) => (
  <input
    type="text"
    onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value)}
    value={value}
  />
);

const App = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState<RuleGroupType>({
    id: "root",
    combinator: "and",
    rules: []
  });

  return (
    <QueryBuilder
      fields={[{ name: "test", label: "Test" }]}
      controlElements={{ valueEditor: ValueEditor }}
      onQueryChange={(q) => setQuery(q)}
      query={query}
    />
  );
};
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/value-editor-rerendering-forked-jrn7pe?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: This is the correct answer, and in fact we have an entire page dedicated to this problem in the documentation: https://react-querybuilder.js.org/docs/tips/common-mistakes#custom-component-as-closure